# Egrep multiple strings in an XML file

Tags: centos, grep, xml

I have a collection of XML files in a standard format that I'd like to search to see if they match two strings.

Here is the idea:

```
<ELEMENT1>Dave</ELEMENT>
<DON'TCARE1>Blaa</DON'TCARE2>
<DON'TCARE2>Blaa2</DON'TCARE2>
<ELEMENT2>History</ELEMENT2>
```

***How can I match the content of ELEMENT1 and ELEMENT2 with egrep and return the filename that contains them?***

Comment: You should first read this to realize how bad it is to use regexps to parse HTML or XML : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454. To look for an element in a XML file, use an XPath expression instead.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `</ELEMENT1>` instead of `</ELEMENT>` above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With recent GNU `grep` built with recent PCRE:

```
grep -Po '<(ELEMENT[12]>)\K.*?(?=</\1)'
```

Answer (score 2):

The following XQuery should give you the desired output :

```
for $x in (/content/element1,/content/element2)
return $x/text()
```

For example, with an XQuery interpreter such as [XQilla](http://xqilla.sourceforge.net/HomePage) and an input file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<content>
   <element1>truc</element1>
   <dontcare>blah</dontcare>
   <dontcare>blah</dontcare>
   <element2>truc2</element2>
   <dontcare>blah</dontcare>
   <dontcare>blah</dontcare>
</content>
```

`xqilla -i 1.xml 1.query` outputs

```
truc
truc2
```

For your example, regexps might be sufficient but in the general case it's a bad idea to use them for XML parsing because XML is not a regular language (i.e. a language parsable with regular expressions).